# Outputting one file in S3 per key in Hadoop/EMR

Tags: hadoop, emr, amazon-emr

Is it possible to have a single file in S3 per key outputted through hadoop/EMR processing? There will be tens of millions of keys. Each key will have hundreds of KBs of data after EMR processing. I want to generate a single file for each key in S3.

The only way I can think of doing this is to write to S3 directly from mapper. What are the pros/cons? Are there other options available? Also, if I have to write it in encrypted format, how can I do that?

Thanks,

-Anil

Answer (score 0):

For the first part of the question you could potentially use MultipleOutputFormat to create an output file for each key. I've never done this with millions of keys so your results may vary. See https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.4.1/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/output/MultipleOutputs.html

For the second part, you can set up encryption both on the EMR cluster and on s3 so that it is handled transparently. 
See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/DeveloperGuide/emr-plan-input-sse.html.